CORS error in angular http.get, without server
I want to run my Angular app without any server/build/etc. For that, I built my app ng build -c=production, but opening the generated index.html isn't easy: I removed <base href="/"> and the type="module"s from script injections, so it started nicely!
But... my "database" is a local CSV file I read up in a common way:
this.http.get('assets/index.csv', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe({ ...
However, when I load the index.html, it throws an CORS error for this CSV, even if the searched location is correct. What should I do to not to have CORS error for these files?
(Angular 16)

An HTTP GET operation is by definition making an AJAX call to a server.  If you don't have (or want) a server then you don't want to use that operation.  Do you mean that you're trying to open a file from the computer's local file system?  That's not an AJAX operation.  That's a File operation.

Yes it's a local file. I see. So there's no way I can solve it with HttpClient!?

Correct.  HttpClient is for making HTTP requests.

Okay, I'll rewrite my code then, not to use HttpClient :) - just like old times. Thanks

I think that if you provide "assets" folder in the angular.json, you should able to access all the files under the "assets" folder via Angular HTTP Client. Maybe you can check you settings there and make sure that the file is in the assets folder.
